# Impacts of Duplicate content on Second-Level-Domain aside SEO

Tags: seo, domains, duplicate-content, hotlinking

A particular website is usually referred by the domain `example.com`, which is also the one which is promoted and used everywhere. But there's also `example.net` (in real, the hyphen in the domain name is removed), which serves the *exact same content*, *including the links and references to images, style information* etc.

I usually oppose to these kind of setups and recommend a 301 Permanent Redirect for reasons of unambiguity, simplicity and single content.

I'm a fan of unambiguity because my background server administration and this is a very important principle, but it's only relevant on the low levels of digital communication. *Are there any other reasons, from the webmaster's and user's view, to oppose to such setups aside from duplicate content in SEO?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate pages (regardless of domain) frustrates users.

Imagine if google's duplicate content penalty was never in place. If a user searched for a term and found it on one of your sites, then your second site will be listed underneath it. If the user did not like the first entry, surely, there will be some sadness because the next entry is the duplicate of the first, and frustration may come if the user just clicks a result without reading the text in the result pages because he then realizes he is going to the same page again.

Now if the page was duplicated hundreds of times, the frustration will rise to the top with many users because your page will then be listed hundreds of times and users will have to keep clicking next page in the search engine until finally new results appeared.

So for the user's sake, eliminate it.

As for the webmaster, it either means you either have to manage the same files twice (if each domain connects to separate servers), or if you use the same server to manage both domains then the server speed may be cut in half, especially when both copies are indexed since search engine users will be visiting both copies frequently in hopes that one is different from the other.